# How do I batch multiple gearman jobs to be handled together by a worker?

Tags: php, gearman

I have multiple clients adding jobs to my gearman queue.

These jobs are documents ultimately destined to be batch uploaded to SOLR for indexing

I would like to grab multiple jobs from my queue and concatinate them together in batches of 1000 documents for performance reasons.

I'm open to using the gearman cmd tool, or any of their SDKs

I've been looking at the PHP extension and the only option $worker->work() is inadequate.

I found a [forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gearman/UyUxjY1VZUg) suggesting the use of grab_job() but that's from 2009 and the method doesnt seem to exist anymore.

Am I using gearman wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you just add the jobs to a database, and if there are enough jobs to batch together, send the batch ID to Gearman, which will then read in the jobs itself?

Comment: @david chan, May i know how did u solve this problem?

Comment: i never solved this.

Answer (score 1):

Your php workers do persist between the jobs. So you can do the following: use $worker->work() in a typical manner - I mean, one job - one work() call. Set a counter inside your worker and save all the job workloads into internal variable. Every 1000 jobs also do your batch processing.